# Why does typescript conditional type does not work in a nested object?

Tags: typescript

The `child` property for PropDesc2 must only exist if `prop` property is `InfoType.files` or `InfoType.catalogParts` or `InfoCatalogPart.datasheets`. This is what I am trying to constraint by creating a type `PropDesc2`.

It typescript check seems to work for `descriptorA`, but does not work for `descriptorB` (because it is nested?).

Is this a limitation of typescript, or I am missing something?

```
export enum InfoType {
    designation = "designation",
    files = "files",
    catalogParts = "catalogParts",
}

export enum InfoFile {
    name = "name",
}

export enum InfoCatalogPart {
    datasheets = "datasheets",
}

export interface PropDesc<T extends InfoType | InfoFile | InfoCatalogPart> {
    prop: T;
    index?: number;
    child?: T extends InfoType.files | InfoType.catalogParts | InfoCatalogPart.datasheets
    ? T extends InfoType.files | InfoCatalogPart.datasheets
    ? PropDesc<InfoFile>
    : T extends InfoType.catalogParts
    ? PropDesc<InfoCatalogPart>
    : never
    : never;
}

export type PropDesc2<T extends InfoType | InfoFile | InfoCatalogPart> =
  T extends InfoType.files
    ? PropDesc<T> & { child: PropDesc<InfoFile> }
    : T extends InfoCatalogPart.datasheets
    ? PropDesc<T> & { child: PropDesc<InfoFile> }
    : T extends InfoType.catalogParts
    ? PropDesc<T> & { child: PropDesc<InfoCatalogPart> }
    : PropDesc<T> & { child: never };

const descriptorA: PropDesc2<InfoCatalogPart> = { //fails because child is missing (as expected)
    prop: InfoCatalogPart.datasheets,
};

const descriptorB: PropDesc2<InfoType> = { //does not fail, but it SHOULD fail
    prop: InfoType.catalogParts,
    child: {
        prop: InfoCatalogPart.datasheets //should fail here because 'child' property is missing
    }
};
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-playground-qxrehf?file=index.ts

Comment: `PropDesc`'s `child` property is always optional, and `PropDesc2<InfoType>`'s `child` property is a `PropDesc`, so the `child` property of the `child` property is always optional.  You wrote quite a complicated set of types here, but TS is doing exactly what you told it to.  If you want `child` to be required in `PropDesc`, you should make it such.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (except I don't really know what you're trying to achieve, so I wouldn't speculate on that).  If not, what am I missing?